# ColdFusion: get amount of results from a query

Tags: coldfusion

I have some ColdFusion output:

```
<cfoutput query="myList">#Email#</cfoutput>
```

If my list happens to have **several results**, this output loops and prints out all the emails. However, if there are **no results**, I would like to write a  statement to output a message...

How does this work? It seems like `#Email#` is a variable, but it can also be an array...how do I count the number of results when using  like this?

update: I have also tried using a stored procedure to do a COUNT, which gives me the amount...but I'm not sure how to use the results of the stored procedure in a coldfusion `<cfif>` statement...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<cfif myList.RecordCount>
  <cfoutput query="myList">#Email#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
  No results
</cfif>
```

is what you are looking for, and is the strategy most commonly employed by ColdFusion developers.

Answer (score 2):

A Query is a Coldfusion-specific datatype that looks like an array of structs but behaves differently.

You can check for the number of records as #myList.recordcount#

```
    <cfif not myList.recordcount>
    No records found
    </cfif>
```